# Aero disabled after computer wakes up from hibernation

Tags: windows-7, hibernate, aero

Sometimes when my computer wakes up from hibernation, Aero is turned off, and I can't enable it again. A simple restart will enable Aero again, so it isn't broken completely. Any idea what may cause this?

I'm running Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit.

**Update:**
Should probably mention that this hasn't been an issue before just recently (started happening within the last couple of days). And I regularly put my computer into hibernation mode (normally 2 times every work day), so I'm quite puzzled as to why it starts to behave like this now.

**Update 2:**
I'm at work now, and I have tried many times to reproduce this problem, both with Standby and Hibernation, and I have not been able to reproduce at all. I use a docking station at work and at home, so I tried to hibernate in the docking station, taking the pc out of the docking station and boot it up again. No problem occurred. I will take note of what happens when I go home today, because then I will hibernate (with the pc in the docking station) here at work, and then resume in the docking station I have at home. I'm suspecting that this might be the problem, but I won't know before I'm at home.

**Update 3:**
Just got home, started my PC in the docking station, and... No problem here... I guess I will have to wait for it to happen again to see if I can figure out something. I will wait until the problem reappears before I test the drivers from laptopvideo2go.com (I don't wanna mess with drivers unless I have to).

Comment: I also have this problem (also W7U64 + laptop). Out of curiousity what is your hardware? I have a t61p with quaddro 570m. This has only recently started happening to me and I suspect it is related to either the installation of lenovo power manager or some recent changes I made in nvidia control panel.

Answer (score 3):

Window Theming is actually performed by a Service. It could be that the theming service somehow didn't start up back up.

Here's a possible fix: http://www.tbak.co.uk/blog/fix-for-themes-service-startup-problems-in-windows-7-and-vista/

Comment: I'll investigate the fix further the next time this happens.

Comment: Thanks for this tip -- restarting the "Desktop Window Manager Session Manager" service restored Aero for me without having to reboot.

Comment: Nice, that works.

Answer (score 0):

Try newest video drivers. Nvidia had similar issues with mobile GeForces. If it's Nvidia, try laptopvideo2go.com

Comment: I have downloaded the latest driver, and I will try to install it when I get home. Just want to test a little more first to see if I can figure out the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried refreshing your Windows Experience Index? Look for something like:

Control Panel > System and Security > System > Windows Experience Index > Re-run the assessment

Comment: I haven't tried that, but I will try it if aero disappears again. Everything seems to be working now, so I will just have to wait and see if it happens again.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem on a similar configuration. Internet searches reveal that several people have had this issue. I can't locate it, but I had come across one thread that said this was an issue in Vista also and hasn't been fixed yet.

Some other threads indicate it could be related to video or motherboard BIOS issues. The BIOS angle makes more sense to me since I've read that Windows will sometimes disable Aero to conserve energy or performance, and sleep is related to power management. I'll try to post if I can find additional information.